# how to publish clickonce to website

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I am trying to publish clickonce wpf application to my website `www.angryapps.co` with the help of visual studio ftp publish method and it published application correctly at `www.angryapps.co/gpacalculator.html"` but when I click install the setup shows error `"Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted"`

**Error Summary**

```
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://angryapps.co/GPACalculatorWPF.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The Deployment Provider specified in the manifest cannot be reached. Maybe due to network error and/or the deployment provider is not responding correctly.
        + Exception reading manifest from http://redirect.main-hosting.com/error404.php/2?domain=angryapps.co: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x8007001f
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:     
        + A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
```

This URL `http://angryapps.co/GPACalculatorWPF.application` is also reachable.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435752/what-are-the-web-server-requirements-for-clickonce-deployment ("What are the web server requirements for ClickOnce deployment?")

Comment: Are you using Windows Server in your hosting? Is a shared environment?